# Angular 2 (+Dart) inline conditionals: Is the second condition evaluated if the first is false? How to solve?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-template

This is the code in my `component.html` (Angular Dart template):

```
<div *ngIf="selectedOffer!=null && !selectedOffer.isBotenOffer">...</div>
```

This is the exception I get:

> EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isBotenOffer' was called on
>   null. Receiver: null Tried calling: isBotenOffer

`selectedOffer` my be `null` sometimes. But why is the second statement evaluated if the first is false? And how can I around this best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular will write this into the generated template file:

`_NgIf_0_5.ngIf = ((ctx.selectedOffer != null) && !ctx.selectedOffer.isBotenOffer);`

So it shouldn't evaluate `selectedOffer.isBotenOffer` if `selectedOffer` is `null`. However, you may be hitting a bug that was just fixed in dart2js: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/fe7baee84828e109a49920c2572f3917e5ff8ca5

You might hit this issue if you are setting `selectedOffer` in your component's constructor, but doing an early return in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

No, with `&&` short-circuit evaluation stops evaluating the 2nd part when the first is `false` - the same as in normal Dart code.